# Way to pass multiple arguments to a function directly from input method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose there is a function `funx`which takes multiple arguments(like `funx(item, quantity, price)` ) and outputs respective values.

Now what i can normally do is call function and pass args with it like this: `funx(Lays, 2, 40)`

But what i'm trying to do is something like this(this throws error though)

```
funx(item, quantity, price = input("use format 'Lays, 2, 40', use commas : ").split(','))
```

to take user input this one time...
I could have done this(and i know its cleaner):

```
def funx(item, quantity, price):
    print(item, quantity, price)

def input_funx():
    item, quantity, price = input("use format 'Lays, 2, 40', use commas : ").split(',')
    return(item, quantity, price)

funx("Monaco", 3, 30)
funx(input_funx())
#but I want some different approach coz i won't be using this input_funx later
```

and could have called `funx(input_funx())` and job done, BUT just exploring if something similar is possible or not.

Here's the error: `funx(input("enter in this format '' Lays, 20, 200 ''...use commas for separation  :  ").split(','))
TypeError: funx() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'quantity' and 'price'`

Note: I explored about lambda functions if it can be used but found it returns single parameter.(correct me if wrong) :3

Is there a way something like this...`funx(item, quantity, price= input("%s,%d,%f"))` ... or any intuitive way(using dictionary or list or anything) which gets job done in SINGLE LINE.

Any help is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: put an example of `funx` being called (in the original format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unpack the 'tuple' that is returned from `.split()` using `*input(...)`:

```
>>> def funx(a1,a2,a3):
...     print(a1,a2,a3)
... 
>>> funx(*input("enter in this format '' Lays, 20, 200 ''...use commas for separation  :  ").split(','))
```

Output:

```
Lays  2  2
```

Comment: Thanks Maurice..that was real quick and super simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use argument expansion and avoid all that:

```
def funx(param1, param2, param3):
    print("Called with params: {}, {}, {}".format(param1, param2, param3))

funx( * input("use format 'Lays, 2, 40', use commas : ").split(","))
# or if you insist on whitespaces:
# funx( * (a.strip() for a in input("use format 'Lays, 2, 40', use commas : ").split(",")))
```

That being said, there is no reason to make your code unreadable and hard to debug.